# How could Vue.js have templateUrl configure just like Angular.js do?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mvvm, angular-ui-router, vue.js

I love the simplicity of Vue.js, but I don't want to complexify it with browserify or webpack. I prefer something like templateUrl in Angular, so I can serve the partial page(usually a component) with Nginx directly. How could I set up this? It's not suggested officially, hard to get help there.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Vue doesn't have anything built in for this specifically as far as I can tell but you'd be able to use [async components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html#Async-Components) to fake it if you wanted to.

```
Vue.component('example', function (resolve, reject) {
  $.get('templates/example.html').done(function (template) {
    resolve({
      template: template
    })
  });
});
```

You'd also be able to do something like this as well in your HTML.

```
<div id="app"></div>

<template id="example">
  <div>
    <h1>{{ message }}</h1>
  </div>
</template>
```

Then you can do like:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {
    example: {
      template: '#example',
      data: function () {
        return {
          message: 'Yo'
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Though, I think taking the time to get comfortable with browserify or webpack is well worth the investment. Especially because you can use [vueify](https://github.com/vuejs/vueify).

Comment: sorry newbie, is this vuejs1 or 2 ? $ is of vuejs ?

Comment: The $ is jQuery. So, just using jQuery's `get` as an example.

Comment: of an async request. You can use whatever you'd want.